# How to enable UX builder for custom post types in Flatsome

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using flatsome theme and design the first page with flatsome ux builder, I created post_type name product. I want to show slider of my custom post_type in first page. does it possible? does anybody know anyway to do it? I can't add shortcode because ,it seems that ux builder can't work properly with shortcode!

Comment: go to below link https://gist.github.com/webseo-onilne/6aaee7a04b33bf3a2f0a4903fa721c2f there is complete answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend here...

From ux themes site: https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/221-how-to-enable-ux-builder-for-custom-post-types

```
/**
 * Code goes in theme functions.php
 */
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if ( function_exists( 'add_ux_builder_post_type' ) ) {
        add_ux_builder_post_type( 'custom_post_type' );
    }
} );
```

You'll want to change 'custom_post_type' to your actual post type.

Comment: rudtek : actually i add this piece of code but i don't now how to show my post type in design with ux builder!

Comment: I would need to see the code you used to create the custom post type.  update your question with that code and I can take a look.